# When appending empyt list, everything will gone empty why?

Tags: python, regex

How to append the empty list with the list without any changes using python3?

```
import re
l=[]
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
sublist2=[]
for i in sublist2:
   list2 = re.sub("[0-9']+", '',i)
l.append(list1)
l.append(list2)
print(l)
```

> Expected Output:

```
 [["a","b","c"],[]]
```

Comment: The list you are iterating over is empty.

Comment: i have made some changes please see the code again

Comment: Indentation is not the problem, you are calling a for loop over an empty list. The loop is never entered.

Comment: The list you are iterating over is still empty.

Comment: It doesn't change anything `sublist` is empty so it never enters the loop. I'm surprised you are not getting an exception `NameError` because `list2` has never been assigned, so referencing it should be an exception.

Comment: ok i understand please someone tell me any other suggestion for this

Comment: @AChampion, they should indeed be getting that exception. I suspect this isn't the version of the code that gave that output... In fact I'd wager it was the first version they posted.

Comment: @pythoncoder you haven't explained what you are trying to do. `l.append([])` appends an empty list but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?

```
import re
l=[]

list1 = ["a","b","c"]

sublist2=[]
list2=[re.sub("[0-9']+", '',i) for i in sublist2]

l.append(list1)
l.append(list2)
print(l)
#result:[['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
```

```
import re
l=[]

list1 = ["a","b","c"]

sublist2=["1","3","f"]
list2=[re.sub("[0-9']+", '',i) for i in sublist2]

l.append(list1)
l.append(list2)
print(l)
#result:[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['', '', 'f']]
```

Answer (score 0):

To append 2 lists in python there is a nice & simple operator doing what you want (appending 2 lists); that operator is: plus `+`.

Look at the following code for example:

```
a = list(range(3))
b = list(range(4, 7))
print(a + b) # output: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]
print(b + a) # output: [4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
l=[]
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
sublist2=[]
l.append(list1)
l.append(sublist2)
print(l)  ## [['a', 'b', 'c'], []]
```